# jquery how to access $(this) and its inline classes

Tags: jquery

Given this HTML:

`<div class="term qtip">something</div>`

I need to access `.term.qtip`

How can I do this if I have `.term` stored as `$(this)` ?

`$(this).find('.qtip')` obviously won't work because it's looking for a child element. What's the solution?

Comment: `$(this).filter('.qtip')`

Comment: @BradM you should answer and not comment, afaik this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).filter('.qtip')
```

This will filter your collection of elements `($(this))` and return only those elements which contain the class "qtip".